# Is there a Web Service API to the Google Product Search?

Tags: web-services, google-product-search

I want to call the Google product search and get back a parse-able XML file rather than having to scrape the HTML.  I'm not looking for a SOAP based service, but a service that returns XML based on a URL passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction--this did NOT work:

The Google Base API lists only a subset of Google product sellers (apparently only those who are active users of the Google Base product.)
http://code.google.com/apis/base/docs/2.0/attrs-queries.html

I eventually ended up using a screen scraping solution and then found that the data was too inconsistant to use for my purposes at all. :-(

Answer (score 0):

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2165-how-to-search-google-and-bing-in-c/

use that refer link ,hopefuly it'll very usefull with you all guys

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.